# Pushing Items into stack with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can i programatically push an array of strings into generic Stack ?

**string array**

```
 string[] array=new string[]{"Liza","Ana","Sandra","Diya"};
```

**Stack Setup**

```
 public class stack<T>
 {
    private int index;

    List<T> list; 

    public stack()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
        index=-1;

    }

    public void Push(T obj)
    {

        list.Add(obj);
        index++;
    }
 ...........
}
```

**What is the change do i need here ?**

```
stack<string> slist = new stack<string>();
var v = from vals in array select (p => slist.Push(p));
```

**Error Report :**

```
The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LINQ is a query language/framework. What you want to perform here is a *modification* to a collection object rather than a query (selection) - this is certainly *not* what LINQ is designed for (or even capable of).

What you might like to do, however, is to define an extension method that for the `Stack<T>` class, however. Note that it also makes sense to here to use the BCL `Stack<T>` type, which is exactly what you need, instead of reinventing the wheel using `List<T>`.

```
public static void PushRange<T>(this Stack<T> source, IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
        source.Push(item);
}
```

Which would then allow you do the following:

```
myStack.PushRange(myCollection);
```

And if you're not already convinced, another philosophical reason: LINQ was created to bring functional paradigms to C#/.NET, and at the core of functional programming is side-effect free code. Combining LINQ with state-modifying code would thus be quite inconsistent.

Comment: Why an extension method? The stack class seems to be written by him, so a normal method would be better imho.

Comment: @Maximillian: Look closer at my code. The method takes a `Stack<T>` parameter, not a `List<T>` one. He seems to be reinventing the wheel here, for which there is no need.

Comment: Ah, you suggest creating an extension method for the BCL's Stack class, not for his. Okay, this makes sense, of course. Sorry for the misunderstading.

Comment: @Maximillian: No worries. :) And yeah, I didn't initially make it explicit that I was instructing him to use `Stack<T>` instead.

Comment: Yes Now I can understand the purpose of linq ! Thanks

Comment: Just a comment on this code, it is possible / probable that you will want to push onto the stack in reverse order here.  Or at least, some consideration on ordering is required.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is you Push returns a void.  Select is expecting a value of something.

You are just doing a loop and don't need to use link.

Since you stack is internally storing a list, you can create a list by passing it an array.

so in your case

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>(array);
```

Creats the list.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void Push(T obj)
```

to

```
public T Push(T obj)
```

and ignore the return values.

Disclaimer: I would not recommend mutation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string[] arr = new string[]{"a","f"};
var stack = new Stack<string>();
arr.ToList().ForEach(stack.Push);
```

While this is "cool" is isn't any better than a for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Push needs a return type for you to be able to use it in a select clause.  As it is, it returns void.  Your example is, I think, a horrible abuse of LINQ.  Even if it worked, you'd be using a side-effect of the function in the select clause to accomplish something totally unrelated to the task that the select is intended for.  If there was a "ForEach" extension, then it would be reasonable to use LINQ here, but I'd avoid it and stick with a foreach loop.

```
 foreach (var val in array)
 {
     slist.Push(val);
 }
```

This is much clearer in intent and doesn't leave one scratching their head over what you're trying to accomplish.