# Pushing a stack to another stack in python

Tags: python, stack

I´m trying to push the content of stack A to stack B. Also I want to keep the order of both stacks. For this I wanted to use a stack C. I tried to do it in the following function:

```
class Stack:
    ...

    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()
        self.topindex -= 1
        return self

    def some_func(A, B, C):
        for item in A.items:
            while A.topindex is not 0:
                A.push(A.pop(item), C)
        for items in C.items:
            while C.topindex is not 0:
                C.push(C.pop(item), B)
    ...
```

topindex is the index of the last item in the stack.
If 2 items are in the stack topindex would be 2.

However when executed an Error is thrown:
TypeError: pop() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I also tried to use this post([Push a stack onto another stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477783/push-a-stack-onto-another-stack)) for help, but that didn´t work for me either, mainly because I don´t know anything about c#.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a complete stack implementation for me to use, but Python's list type already has a pop method, so you can use them like stacks.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = []
>>> c = []
>>> while a:
    c.append(a.pop())


>>> c
[3, 2, 1]
>>> while c:
    b.append(c.pop())


>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[]
>>> c
[]
```

There are easier ways to manipulate lists, but the above is how you would move the elements of a stack using only push(append)/pop.

Your stack implementation should have an equivalent of `.append()` and `.pop()`, and some way to tell if it is empty to end the while loop.

Comment: Ahh yeah sure, I could have thought about that.
Thanks for your help!